# Creating a FIFO fixed size array in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I'm attempting to create a FIFO array in swift.  I want to create something that acts like this:

```
var Arr = FixedFIFOArray<Int>(maxSize:3)
Arr.append(1)  //Arr = [1]
Arr.append(2)  //Arr = [1,2]
Arr.append(3)  //Arr = [1,2,3]
Arr.append(4)  //Arr = [2,3,4] <- the max size is fixed to 3, so any
                                  additional values added remove old values
```

Other than this behavior, it should act like an array:  allow slicing, indexing, iterating in `for` loops, etc.

In any other language, this would be a job for subclassing.  We aren't changing much, just adding an initializer and amending a function or two.  However, in Swift, we can't subclass `array`.  What is the best way to do this?  Do I need to implement every protocol that `array` implements, and just pass the associated functions off to an array?  Something like this:

```
struct FixedFIFOArray<T> {
    var _maxSize: Int
    var _array: [T] = []

    init(maxSize: Int) {
        self._maxSize = maxSize
    }

}

extension FixedFIFOArray : Collection {
    //...
}

extension FixedFIFOArray : RandomAccessCollection {
    //...
}

extension FixedFIFOArray : Sequence {
    //...
}
// etc...
```

This seems like a *lot* of work to do something so simple.  What am I missing?

Comment: maybe you could write an extension for array where you define a different append function something like appendFIFO(element: T, forSize: Int). It depends on the usecase but maybe thats enough

Comment: I thought of the same approach. You would also need a function to trim an array to keep just the last n items.

Comment: Most protocol methods have default implementations. It suffices to implement startIndex, endIndex, and subscript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not as bad as it seems, because many protocol requirements have
default implementations.
Unfortunately I do not have the perfect recipe to find a "minimal" implementation.

- Some information can be found in the
  [`RandomAccessCollection` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/randomaccesscollection)
  where some methods are marked as *"Required. Default implementation provided."*
- You can also start with an empty implementation `extension FixedFIFOArray : RandomAccessCollection {}` and study the error messages or try the Fix-its.
- With "Jump to Definiton" in the Xcode editor one can inspect the protocol definitions and extension methods.

In your case it turned out that it suffices to implement 
`startIndex`, `endIndex`, and `subscript`:

```
extension FixedFIFOArray : RandomAccessCollection {
    var startIndex: Int {
        return _array.startIndex
    }

    var endIndex: Int {
        return _array.endIndex
    }

    subscript(i: Int) -> T {
        return _array[i]
    }
}
```

Or, if you need a read-write subscript:

```
    subscript(i: Int) -> T {
        get {
            return _array[i]
        }
        set {
            _array[i] = newValue
        }
    }
```